# f:validateLongRange instantiating a Bean where it should not

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have the following validator:

```
<h:inputText id="orderC" value="#{columnEdit.selectedColumn.position}"  maxlength="2" validatorMessage="#{columnEdit.valOrder}">
             <f:validateLongRange maximum="#{columnEdit.maxOrder}" minimum="#{columnEdit.minOrder}" />
</h:inputText>
```

The validator belongs to a *JSF* page whose backing bean is *ViewScoped*.

The relevant code snippets:

```
public Integer getMaxOrder()
    {
        maxOrder = selectedFileFormat.getColumnList().size();

        return maxOrder;
    }
```

_

```
public Integer getMinOrder()
    {
       if (getIsCode())
          {
             minOrder = 1;
          }
          else
          {
             minOrder = 2;
          }

          return minOrder;
    }
```

_

```
public String getValOrder()
    {
        valOrder = "Range of " + minOrder + " to " + maxOrder;

        return valOrder;
    }
```

_
There is a *cancel* button on my page:

```
 <p:commandButton value="#{i18n['xxx.cancel']}" action="#{columnEdit.cancel}" ajax="false">
                  <p:confirmDialog message="#{i18n['xxx.cancelConf']}" severity="warn" />
                  <f:param name="formatId" value="#{columnEdit.selectedFileFormat.id}"/>
                  <f:param name="navigationCase" value="edit"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

_
Whose action:

```
public String cancel()
    {
        Integer theFormatId = selectedFileFormat.getId();

        return "fileFormatEdit.xhtml"
    }
```

_
**My Question:** why is the postConstruct of my bean being called after pressing the cancel button? I found that the cause is the `f:validateLongRange` but why is it instantiating a new *columnEdit* bean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does f:validateDoubleRange only work for @SessionScoped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445417/why-does-fvalidatedoublerange-only-work-for-sessionscoped)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're are specifically defining the next view to navigate by return "fileFormatEdit.xhtml" ?

If you mean to return to the same page, try changing to return null (meaning no navigation, and make use the current active view).

Or simply change the action method definition to public void cancel(), where you dont have to return anything.

Comment: Hi :) This old topic gave me a deja vu. I've answered a very similar issue before. Check the possible dupe link which I posted on the question and also [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) for the correct explanation of the problem.

Comment: @BalusC: Hello =) the possible duplicate page is awesome, never had that before. Darn, i didnt notice that the original poster mentioned "f:validateLongRange" is the root cause. I was just having this struck from my experience that although it's a view scope, returning to the current view using explicit return statement will re-create the view scope bean. Hope your solution works for the original poster. Thanks for sharing BalusC !