# JSF2 disabled attribute for validator evaluated only for first cycle?

Tags: validation, jsf-2

I found that disabled attribute for any validator I use in JSF2 is evaluated only in the first cycle if my managed bean is ViewScoped.

But I would like to make use of *disabled* attribute for my validators based on data I get from 4th update phase. So I would expect it reevaluated in all cycles performed on the same view.

Example xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid id="pnlGrid">          
            <h:inputText id="someValueId" value="#{testPageBean.someValue}">                
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="4" 
                   disabled="#{testPageBean.disableValidateLength}"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:messages for="someValueId"/>

            <h:commandButton action="#{testPageBean.doSomething}" 
               value="Do something" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and its **view scoped** managed bean

```
package cz.kamosh;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestPageBean implements Serializable {

    boolean disableValidateLength = false;

    private String someValue;

    public TestPageBean() {
        System.out.println("Constructor TestPageBean");
    }

    public String getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

    public void setSomeValue(String someValue) {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    /**
     *  Some action without any navigation as a result
     */
    public void doSomething() {
        disableValidateLength = !disableValidateLength;
        System.out.printf(
                "DoSomething, someValue: %1$s, disableValidateLength: %2$b\n",
                someValue, disableValidateLength);
    }

    public boolean isDisableValidateLength() {
        System.out.printf("IsValidateLength, disableValidateLength: %1$b\n", 
                disableValidateLength);
        return disableValidateLength;
    }
}
```

I know that I should blame implementation *com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl*:

```
private void applyNested(FaceletContext ctx,
                             UIComponent parent) {

        // only process if it's been created
        if (!ComponentHandler.isNew(parent)) {
            return;
        }
    ...
}
```

These three rows cause validator not being reevaluated its *disabled* attribute when I perform action:-(

Could some please give me a hint, what was the motivation for JSF2 guys to implement  this way or even better how to solve my problem?

***EDIT:***

Version of JSF2: *2.0.3-SNAPSHOT*

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>JSF2Testing</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

---

***EDIT2*** Attempt to follow [BalusC' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445417/why-does-fvalidatedoublerange-only-work-for-sessionscoped)

Changes on page:

```
<h:inputText id="someValueId" value="#{testPageBean.someValue}">                
    <f:validator validatorId="myLengthValidator"/>
    <f:attribute name="disableMyLengthValidator" value="#{testPageBean.disableValidateLength}"/>
    <f:attribute name="minimum" value="2" />
    <f:attribute name="maximum" value="4" />
</h:inputText>
```

Own validator used instead of standard :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator("myLengthValidator")
public class MyLengthValidator extends LengthValidator implements Serializable {

    public MyLengthValidator() {
        System.out.println("MyLengthValidator constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {     
        if((Boolean)component.getAttributes().get("disableMyLengthValidator")) {
            return;
        }       
        setMinimum(Integer.valueOf((String)component.getAttributes().get("minimum")));
        setMaximum(Integer.valueOf((String)component.getAttributes().get("maximum")));
        super.validate(context, component, value);
    }
}
```

My notes about this solution:

- requires own implementation even if for standard validators
- is dependent on attributes on component (inputText) level
- validator is triggered even if it should not be
- I am pretty sure it will not behave as we expect when client side validation is provided for validator
- I consider is as very ugly and not following JSF2 :-(

Answer (score 0):

You've become another victim of the chicken-egg issue with partial state saving and view scoped beans as described in [issue 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492) which is to be fixed in the upcoming Mojarra 2.2.

You should also immediately have realized that something's not entirely right when you saw the constructor of a view scoped bean being invoked on *every request* instead of only once at the first request of a view.

One of the ways to fix it is to disable the partial state saving altogether:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2 - `@ViewScoped` fails in tag handlers](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers)
- [Why does f:validateDoubleRange only work for @SessionScoped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445417/why-does-fvalidatedoublerange-only-work-for-sessionscoped)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I explicitly set PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING as you described. But _disabled_ attribute is still not being reavaluating. Constructor of managed bean is called only once for the first time. After action is performed, constructor is not called and all 6 phases are passed, but method _isDisableValidateLength_ is not called.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. The method is not called in subsequent requests. It's called only once during creation of the view. I'm seeing this behaviour in both Mojarra 2.1.4 and MyFaces 2.1.3. I'd suggest to approach it as described in my answer in the 2nd "See also" link.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I went through your link and tried to implement some solution (see Edit2). I do not know whether I understood well what you suggested. But anyway I do not like the solution I proposed. So if you have any idea how to solve in more clear way I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'd report this to the JSF guys.

Comment: @BalusC Hi, its weird because I get this behavior with disabled but not with rendered.