# Can I tell JSF that an f:attribute applies to some part of my composite component?

Tags: java, jsf-2, attributes, composite-component

In the following example, can I somehow tell JSF that an `<f:attribute>` applies to some specific component, just like I can use `for="..."` in `<f:convertNumber for="...">` and `<f:validator for="...">`?

```
<mytags:myCcInputWithValueHolder id="myparent" item="#{myBean.myDouble}" >
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" for="myinput"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="bindableDoubleRangeValidator" for="myinput"/>
    <f:attribute name="minimum" value="#{30.00}"/>
    <f:attribute name="maximum" value="#{39.99}"/>
</mytags:myCcInputWithValueHolder>
```

Background:

Following [BalusC's solution to a JSF issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445417/why-does-fvalidatedoublerange-only-work-for-sessionscoped/7447265#7447265), I use a custom validator. To feed that validator with some parameters, `<f:attribute>` is used.

Next, when using a composite component with `EditableValueHolder` I can (in fact: *must*) assign the validator to an actual `h:inputText`. But I fail to do the same for the `f:attribute`s, so these are added to the calling parent component instead. For example:

```
<composite:attribute name="item" .../>
<composite:editableValueHolder name="myinput" targets="myinputtext"/>        
:
<h:inputText id="myinputtext" value="#{cc.attrs.item}">
    <!-- <composite:insertChildren /> doesn't change anything -->
</h:inputText>
```

...used with `<f:validator for="myinput" ...>` as shown on top of this post, binds the validator to `myparent:myinputtext`, but the attributes are bound to `myparent`.

Workarounds:

The [documentation for `<f:attribute>` indeed states](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/attribute.html):

> Add an attribute to the UIComponent associated with the closest parent UIComponent custom action.

And given that, the following composite component also works as expected:

```
<composite:attribute name="item" .../>
<composite:attribute name="min" .../>
<composite:attribute name="max" .../>
:
<h:inputText id="myinput" value="#{cc.attrs.item}">
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="bindableDoubleRangeValidator"/>
    <f:attribute name="minimum" value="#{cc.attrs.min}"/>
    <f:attribute name="maximum" value="#{cc.attrs.max}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

...with:

```
<mytags:myCcInputWithValidator 
   item="#{myBean.myDouble}" min="#{30.00}" max="#{39.99}"/>
```

Also, I can easily extend [BalusC's BindableDoubleRangeValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445417/why-does-fvalidatedoublerange-only-work-for-sessionscoped/7447265#7447265) to recurse into the parent components to get the value:

```
Object getAttribute(FacesContext c, UIComponent component, String name) {
    Object result = component.getAttributes().get(name);
    if (result == null && component.getParent() != null) {
        result = getAttribute(c, component.getParent(), name);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Still: any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed nasty. The `<f:attribute>` is indeed specific to the closest parent `UIComponent`. If you nest it in a composite, then it would be specific to the composite component itself. One way would be to just copy the attributes from the composite to the input component in question:

```html
<h:inputText id="myinputtext" value="#{cc.attrs.item}">
    <f:attribute name="minimum" value="#{cc.attrs.minimum}"/>
    <f:attribute name="maximum" value="#{cc.attrs.maximum}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

so that the first code snippet in your question would work.

As to your last code snippet, simpler would be to get the composite component parent by [`UIComponent#getCompositeComponentParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCompositeComponentParent%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) instead.

```
Object getCompositeParentAttribute(UIComponent component, String name) {
    UIComponent composite = UIComponent.getCompositeComponentParent(component);
    return composite.getAttributes().get(name);
}
```

After all, I'd just opt for a new composite, if necessary using the same template as the original composite with help of `<ui:decorate>`. Composites are meant to minimize repeated boilerplate.

```html
<my:inputDouble value="..." min="..." max="..." />
```

with

```html
<cc:implementation>
    <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/someCommonTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="input">
            <h:inputText id="myinput" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
                <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
                <f:validator validatorId="bindableDoubleRangeValidator"/>
                <f:attribute name="minimum" value="#{cc.attrs.min}"/>
                <f:attribute name="maximum" value="#{cc.attrs.max}"/>
            </h:inputText>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>
</cc:implementation>
```