# Since upgraded to JSF2.0, Client ID:FormID:ComponentID being preceded to the validation message while using f:validateDoubleRange

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have upgraded from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.0. Earlier I was using f:validateLongRange or f:validateDoubleRange and the validation worked fine. However, since I have migrated to JSF 2.0 the validation message precedes with client ID which looks something like below :
FormID:ClientID:0:ComponentID in my case, the message appears as

```
premiumCategory:j_idt368:0:tlNewLOS: Validation Error: Specified attribute
                is not between the expected values of 1 and 999,999.
```

There is a [Jira](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2278) which talks about prefixing ClientID but I dont think its of any use to me. 
I learnt  from the blog Communication in JSF 2.0 these  tag handlers do not work correctly in JSF 2.0 thus we should create  custom validators using f:validator

I followed BalusC’s answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445417/why-does-fvalidatedoublerange-only-work-for-sessionscoped); The only difference was I did not get my max and min values from the bean, I specified them in the xhtml,it still printed the validation message as stated above.

While debugging I realised that the client ID is generated as FormID:ClientID:0:ComponentID and  is stored in the UIComponent instance which gets  passed to the MessageFactory.getMessage method. 
The same blog which I mentioned before has a topic in it saying "Ajax rendering of content outside form" which I thought would have a solution to my issue, but again no luck.

Now I have my own custom validator class which extends to DoubleRangeValidator and overrides validate method. I get the desired message. However, I am not convinced that writing a custom validator for each f:validatorXXXX component is the solution.

I am still on my learning curve, can anyone explain me why and where  MessageFactory.getMessage binds these IDs to to the faces message? 
Please advise, 
Dakshata Gulkhobare

Answer (score 0):

The label is overrideable by setting the `label` attribute on the input component of interest.

```
<h:inputText ... label="Your label" />
```

This way the validation message will be formatted as follows:

> Your label: Validation Error: Specified attribute
>                   is not between the expected values of 1 and 999,999

Otherwise it will indeed default to the component's client ID.

If you happen to use `<h:outputLabel>` already and would like to use exactly its value, but don't want to duplicate it into the `label` attribute of every single input component, then you may find [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:outputLabel>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputLabel) helpful.